# Units for CSS transition-duration

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Is `s` for seconds the only unit I can use for time values in CSS transition or animations. Can't find anything about it in the specs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use s(seconds) and ms(milli seconds)

**transition-duration property**

> Syntax
>
> transition-duration:  [ ,  ] * Property values
>
> One or more transition times, separated by commas.
>
> time
>
> ```
> Floating-point number, followed by a time units designator (ms or s).
> ```
>
> Values and Units Reference.

Answer (score 2):

you can use milliseconds `ms` also

> Definition and Usage
>
> The transition-duration property specifies how many seconds (s) or
>   milliseconds (ms) a transition effect takes to complete.

[Look att w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-duration.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Duration and delay properties in transition are defined with seconds (s) or milliseconds (ms).

Reference: https://kolosek.com/css-transition/